packet filtering on macOS: How to emulate a split–brain in a Hazelcast cluster locally
Hazelcast Open Source Edition 3.12.
I start 5 nodes. To explicitly manage their configuration, I built the following hierarchy:
bin
├╴hazelcast.yaml
├╴node-1
│ └╴hazelcast.yaml
├╴node-2
│ └╴hazelcast.yaml
├╴node-3
│ └╴hazelcast.yaml
├╴node-4
│ └╴hazelcast.yaml
└╴node-5
  └╴hazelcast.yaml

Here is the hazelcast.yaml in the root:
hazelcast:
  network:
    interfaces:
      enabled: true
      interfaces: [127.0.0.*]
    port:
      auto-increment: false
    join:
      multicast:
        enabled: false
      tcp-ip:
        enabled: true
        member-list:
          - 127.0.0.1:5701
          - 127.0.0.1:5702
          - 127.0.0.1:5703
          - 127.0.0.1:5704
          - 127.0.0.1:5705

And here are the hazelcast.yamls for node-i:
hazelcast:
  import:
    - ../hazelcast.yaml
  instance-name: hz-node-$i
  network:
    port:
      port: 570$i
    outbound-ports: [337$i1-337$i5]
    join:
      tcp-ip:
        interface: 127.0.0.1

I used $i in the yamls just to illustrate how their content changes depending on the node number.
Now I want to emulate a split–brain scenario by dropping all communication between nodes-1,2,3 and nodes-4,5. To achieve this, I created pf (Packet Filter) rules in /etc/pf.anchors/hazelcast:
block out quick on lo0 proto tcp from 127.0.0.1 port 33711:33715 to 127.0.0.1 port 5704
block out quick on lo0 proto tcp from 127.0.0.1 port 33721:33725 to 127.0.0.1 port 5704
block out quick on lo0 proto tcp from 127.0.0.1 port 33731:33735 to 127.0.0.1 port 5704

block in  quick on lo0 proto tcp from 127.0.0.1 port 33711:33715 to 127.0.0.1 port 5704
block in  quick on lo0 proto tcp from 127.0.0.1 port 33721:33725 to 127.0.0.1 port 5704
block in  quick on lo0 proto tcp from 127.0.0.1 port 33731:33735 to 127.0.0.1 port 5704

block out quick on lo0 proto tcp from 127.0.0.1 port 33711:33715 to 127.0.0.1 port 5705
block out quick on lo0 proto tcp from 127.0.0.1 port 33721:33725 to 127.0.0.1 port 5705
block out quick on lo0 proto tcp from 127.0.0.1 port 33731:33735 to 127.0.0.1 port 5705

block in  quick on lo0 proto tcp from 127.0.0.1 port 33711:33715 to 127.0.0.1 port 5705
block in  quick on lo0 proto tcp from 127.0.0.1 port 33721:33725 to 127.0.0.1 port 5705
block in  quick on lo0 proto tcp from 127.0.0.1 port 33731:33735 to 127.0.0.1 port 5705

block out quick on lo0 proto tcp from 127.0.0.1 port 33741:33745 to 127.0.0.1 port 5701
block out quick on lo0 proto tcp from 127.0.0.1 port 33741:33745 to 127.0.0.1 port 5702
block out quick on lo0 proto tcp from 127.0.0.1 port 33741:33745 to 127.0.0.1 port 5703

block in  quick on lo0 proto tcp from 127.0.0.1 port 33741:33745 to 127.0.0.1 port 5701
block in  quick on lo0 proto tcp from 127.0.0.1 port 33741:33745 to 127.0.0.1 port 5702
block in  quick on lo0 proto tcp from 127.0.0.1 port 33741:33745 to 127.0.0.1 port 5703

block out quick on lo0 proto tcp from 127.0.0.1 port 33751:33755 to 127.0.0.1 port 5701
block out quick on lo0 proto tcp from 127.0.0.1 port 33751:33755 to 127.0.0.1 port 5702
block out quick on lo0 proto tcp from 127.0.0.1 port 33751:33755 to 127.0.0.1 port 5703

block in  quick on lo0 proto tcp from 127.0.0.1 port 33751:33755 to 127.0.0.1 port 5701
block in  quick on lo0 proto tcp from 127.0.0.1 port 33751:33755 to 127.0.0.1 port 5702
block in  quick on lo0 proto tcp from 127.0.0.1 port 33751:33755 to 127.0.0.1 port 5703

At the end of /etc/pf.conf, I added:
anchor "hazelcast/*"
load anchor "hazelcast" from "/etc/pf.anchors/hazelcast"

Then I ran the command:
sudo pfctl -Evf /etc/pf.conf

It printed:
...
Loading anchor hazelcast from /etc/pf.anchors/hazelcast
block drop out quick on lo0 inet proto tcp from 127.0.0.1 port 33741:33745 to 127.0.0.1 port = 5701
block drop out quick on lo0 inet proto tcp from 127.0.0.1 port 33741:33745 to 127.0.0.1 port = 5702
block drop out quick on lo0 inet proto tcp from 127.0.0.1 port 33741:33745 to 127.0.0.1 port = 5703
block drop out quick on lo0 inet proto tcp from 127.0.0.1 port 33751:33755 to 127.0.0.1 port = 5701
block drop out quick on lo0 inet proto tcp from 127.0.0.1 port 33751:33755 to 127.0.0.1 port = 5702
block drop out quick on lo0 inet proto tcp from 127.0.0.1 port 33751:33755 to 127.0.0.1 port = 5703
block drop out quick on lo0 inet proto tcp from 127.0.0.1 port 33711:33715 to 127.0.0.1 port = 5704
block drop out quick on lo0 inet proto tcp from 127.0.0.1 port 33721:33725 to 127.0.0.1 port = 5704
block drop out quick on lo0 inet proto tcp from 127.0.0.1 port 33731:33735 to 127.0.0.1 port = 5704
block drop out quick on lo0 inet proto tcp from 127.0.0.1 port 33711:33715 to 127.0.0.1 port = 5705
block drop out quick on lo0 inet proto tcp from 127.0.0.1 port 33721:33725 to 127.0.0.1 port = 5705
block drop out quick on lo0 inet proto tcp from 127.0.0.1 port 33731:33735 to 127.0.0.1 port = 5705
block drop in quick on lo0 inet proto tcp from 127.0.0.1 port 33741:33745 to 127.0.0.1 port = 5701
block drop in quick on lo0 inet proto tcp from 127.0.0.1 port 33741:33745 to 127.0.0.1 port = 5702
block drop in quick on lo0 inet proto tcp from 127.0.0.1 port 33741:33745 to 127.0.0.1 port = 5703
block drop in quick on lo0 inet proto tcp from 127.0.0.1 port 33751:33755 to 127.0.0.1 port = 5701
block drop in quick on lo0 inet proto tcp from 127.0.0.1 port 33751:33755 to 127.0.0.1 port = 5702
block drop in quick on lo0 inet proto tcp from 127.0.0.1 port 33751:33755 to 127.0.0.1 port = 5703
block drop in quick on lo0 inet proto tcp from 127.0.0.1 port 33711:33715 to 127.0.0.1 port = 5704
block drop in quick on lo0 inet proto tcp from 127.0.0.1 port 33721:33725 to 127.0.0.1 port = 5704
block drop in quick on lo0 inet proto tcp from 127.0.0.1 port 33731:33735 to 127.0.0.1 port = 5704
block drop in quick on lo0 inet proto tcp from 127.0.0.1 port 33711:33715 to 127.0.0.1 port = 5705
block drop in quick on lo0 inet proto tcp from 127.0.0.1 port 33721:33725 to 127.0.0.1 port = 5705
block drop in quick on lo0 inet proto tcp from 127.0.0.1 port 33731:33735 to 127.0.0.1 port = 5705
pf enabled
Token : 14399845021355597821

Now I start the node-1 and node-4. In the log of the node-1, I see:
Initialized new cluster connection between /127.0.0.1:33711 and /127.0.0.1:5704

What am I doing wrong?
